# Undefined variable: tasks (0) when trying to output every database(Tasks) entry associated to one main database entry (Projects)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new to laravel, and trying to output every task associated 
    with a project, everything works fine when i comment out the part 
    about the tasks.

```
The problematic part of the view(show.blade.php):
<div>
  @foreach($project->$tasks as $task)
      <li>{{$task->description}}</li>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

When i go into php artisan tinker everything shows up just fine

```
>>> App\Project::first()->tasks;
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#892
 all: [
   App\Task {#3200
     id: 1,
     project_id: 1,
     description: "Buy a map",
     completed: 0,
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,
   },
   App\Task {#3201
     id: 2,
     project_id: 1,
     description: "Inform friends",
     completed: 1,
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,
   },
 ],
}


The exact error message i get when trying to load the view:

ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: tasks
```

Comment: you don't seems to push the $task variable to your view.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I fixed it, i'm sorry for wasting your time, i forgot that tasks isnt a variable, it is a database, when i deleted the $ everything worked out fine, again, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you don't seems to push the $task variable to your view. from your controller you can do something like this:

```
public function Showtask()
{
 $data['project']=DB::table('your-table')->get();

 return view('show',$data);

}
```

your view

```
<div>
  @foreach($project as $task)
      <li>{{$task->description}}</li>
  @endforeach
</div>
```